# How to get the only the latest record from an inserted id?

Tags: php, mysql

How to get the only the latest record from an inserted id?

Table in image:

[image: image table]

I use this code

```
$result = $this->db->select(quantity)->limit(1)->where('quantity', 'id')->get("tbl_warehouses_products")->row();
$quantity= $result->quantity;
```

Note: by this code I see $quantity value is : 0
but the result I want to get is : 200, because it is the last quantity I have in stock this in the result

Comment: MySQL <> SQL Server - please correct your tags.

Comment: As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Comment: Which quantity is 0 - there are 2? id 24 & id 28.

Comment: di = 28   and  warehouse_id = 4  end product_id =28

Comment: Add the clarification to your question please. I'm guessing you need an order by, but not sure how in the tools you are using.

Comment: What makes something the "latest"?  Conceptually, database rows have no ordering unless you supply an ORDER BY in your select

Comment: Show the output for `SELECT VERSION();`.

Comment: Just an **order by id desc**